# %Rpush >> lists of complex objects (e.g. pandas DataFrames in IPython Notebook)

Tags: r, ggplot2, ipython, jupyter-notebook

Once again, I am having a great time with Notebook and the emerging rmagic infrastructure, but I have another question about the bridge between the two.  Currently I am attempting to pass several subsets of a pandas DataFrame to R for visualization with ggplot2.  Just to be clear upfront, I know that I could pass the entire DataFrame and perform additional subsetting in R.  My preference, however, is to leverage the data management capability of Python and the subset-wise operations I am performing are just easier and faster using pandas than the equivalent operations in R.  So for the sake of efficiency and morbid curiosity...

I have been trying to figure out if there is a way to push several objects at once.  The wrinkle is that sometimes I don't know in advance how many items will need to be pushed. To retain flexibility, I have been populating dictionaries with DataFrames throughout the front end of the script.  The following code provides a reasonable facsimile of what I am working through (I have not converted via com.convert_to_r_dataframe for simplicity, but my real code does take this step):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
%load_ext rmagic 

d1=DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))
d2=DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4))

d_list=[d1,d2]
names=['n1','n2']

d_dict=dict(zip(names,d_list))

for name in d_dict.keys():
    exec '%s=d_dict[name]' % name

%Rpush n1
```

As can be seen, I can assign a static name and push the DataFrame into the R namespace individually (as well as in a 'list' >> %Rpush n1 n2).  What I cannot do is something like the following:

```
for name in d_dict.keys():
    %Rpush d_dict[name]
```

That snippet raises an exception >> KeyError: u'd_dict[name]'.  I also tried to deposit the dynamically named DataFrames in a list, the list references end up pointing to the data rather than the object reference:

```
df_list=[]
for name in d_dict.keys():
    exec '%s=d_dict[name]' % name
    exec 'df_list.append(%s)' % name

print df_list

for df in df_list:
    %Rpush df

[    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15,     
0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19]
```

%Rpush did not throw an exception when I looped through the lists contents, but the DataFrames could not be found in the R namespace.  I have not been able to find much discussion of this topic beyond talk about the conversion of lists to R vectors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rmagic's push uses the name that you give it both to look up the Python variable, and to name the R variable it creates. So it needs a valid *name*, not just any expression, on both sides.

There's a trick you can do to get the name from a Python variable:

```
d1=DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4))
name = 'd1'
%Rpush {name}
# equivalent to %Rpush d1
```

But if you want to do more advanced things, it's best to get hold of the `r` object and use that to put your objects in. Rmagic is just a convenience wrapper over rpy2, which is a full API. So you can do:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r
r.assign('a', 1)
```

You can mix and match which interface you use - rmagic and rpy2 are talking to the same instance of R.

Comment: Once again, thanks for the (prompt) response.  I'll give integrating rpy2 directly a shot.